# Detecting media queries via javascript and apply appropriate data-state

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I need javascript #help.

I have an object(#objID) with three different data state (A B & C) (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn19k87eu2hp8ow/data-states.jpg?dl=0)... Each state contain some css to describe the look of it..

I want to use javascript to detect media queries change and add the appropriate data state to #objID.

(ie. 
if screen is under 320px then add [data-state="A"] to #objID

or if screen is between 320px and 728px then switch to [data-state="B"]

or if screen is above 1024px then switch to [data-state="C"]

)
similar to this concept..http://zerosixthree.se/detecting-media-queries-with-javascript/

but im not sure how to implement it.
Please help.  Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify you can do something like this:

```
window.matchMedia("(max-width: 320px)").addListener(function() {
    // Change the value of `data-state`
});

window.matchMedia("(min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 728px)").addListener(function() {
    // Change the value of `data-state`
});
```

However you need make sure the browser supports `window.matchMedia` and also handles maintaining state etc to know when you've crossed from one breakpoint and into the other and identify which is active as both will trigger as you exit and enter breakpoints.

As for doing it on `window.onresize` this is not a very performant way to do this and you must throttle/debounce if you do it that way. Using matchMedia will only trigger when the breakpoint changes rather than continuously on resize. It also give you the benefit of keeping your CSS media breakpoints in sync with your JS.

[This is a Polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/blob/master/matchMedia.addListener.js) for browsers which do not support it as mentioned and [this guide](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/) might also help you.

**However:**

> I have an object(#objID) with three different data state (A B & C).
>   Each state contain some css to describe the look of it..

Sounds as though you want to change the CSS styles applied to an element based on the `data-state` attribute, which you are going to change per breakpoint?

Correct me if I am wrong but why can't you just use media queries to change the CSS that is applied to it instead?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* State A */
   .css-selector {
        color: red;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 728px) {
    /* State B */
   .css-selector {
        color: green;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
   /* State C */
   .css-selector {
        color: blue;
   }
}
```

Comment: The question has defined the 'state' as a bunch of CSS styles as quoted. If however, the OP requires the 'data-state' for anything else other than this then this indeed is not the answer.

Comment: He also stated he wants to do this with Javascript.

Comment: You'll be surprised how often people ask the wrong questions to achieve their goal.

He also stated he wanted to do it with media queries not `window.onresize` so I've updated my answer.

Comment: "I want to use javascript to detect media queries change and add the appropriate data state to #objID" He clearly asked us to give him some Javascript solution to catch the event. He could not phrase window.onresize, since he was not aware of its existence. I would not be surprised, but I do not intend to encourage people to ask something they are not curious about. Questions should be specific and answers should relate to questions. The op clearly wanted to change data state, which cannot be controlled by css in some cases. You can edit your answer to fix it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `onresize` event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //...
};
```

The screen has two dimensions, `width` and `height`, and you describe a one-dimensional comparison, which does not give us enough information about what you want to achieve. Anyway, you can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` inside your `onresize` event.